# Mail sending laravel 7

Tags: laravel

my env file is as below

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=support@company.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=kh=*****&***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Is this set up correct? I am getting response code "535" while expecting code 235.

Comment: read this https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/54327606.html

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
Replace: MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
With: MAIL_PASSWORD="yourpassword"
```

Also run the following command to clear cache.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Above command is all in one.

[image]

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by clicking on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by clicking upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0):

Please add double quote "" in your email password & try

Like:

MAIL_PASSWORD=kh*****&***

TO

MAIL_PASSWORD="kh*****&***"

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do change in .env file
Run "php artisan optimize:clear"
It will clear your cache etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=support@company.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="kh=*****&***"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

And then run `php artisan optimize:clear` for clearing your laravel cache.

If still not working try these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your code first? then programmer can find problem. If you dont want to show full code then you should restart serve `php artisan serve` as you have changed you `.env` file.